Remove duplicate values ​from text, ignoring case (keeping original)
It is necessary to remove duplicate values ​​from the original cell value, ignoring their case, but after removal, keep unique values ​​with the original case (first occurrences).
Original cell value (e.g. A1):
Apple, banana, CHERRY, OrAnGe, kIWi, GrapE, apple, APPLE, ApPlE, aPPLe, ApplE, Apple, Banana, BANANA, BaNaNa, bANANa, BananA, banana, Cherry, cherry, ChErRy, cHERRy, CherrY, CHERRY, Orange, orange, ORANGE, oRANGe, OrangE, OrAnGe, Kiwi, kiwi, KiWi, KiwI, kIWi, Grape, grape, GRAPE, GrApE, gRAPe, GrapE

Expected cell value (e.g. A2) with formula:
Apple, banana, CHERRY, OrAnGe, kIWi, GrapE


You can use:
=LET(
  s,SPLIT(A1,", "),
  j,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(s)),
  JOIN(", ",FILTER(s,1=COUNTIFS(s,s,j,"<="&j))))

The formula splits the string by the comma and space, filters the values whose current count is exactly 1 and joins them together.

You can try this Google sheet formula:
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, UNIQUE(FILTER(TOCOL(SPLIT(A1, ", ")), MATCH(LOWER(TOCOL(SPLIT(A1, ", "))), LOWER(TOCOL(SPLIT(A1, ", "))), 0) = SEQUENCE(COUNTA(SPLIT(A1, ", "))))))

It first splits each text, converts them to lowercase, finds the first occurrence of each word, filters the original values based on those first occurrences, and then removes duplicates.
References:

Filter
Match
Lower
Sequence



You may try:
=let(Σ,split(A1,", ",),Λ,sequence(1,counta(Σ)),
 textjoin(", ",1,map(Σ,Λ,lambda(x,y,if(countif(filter(Σ,Λ<=y),x)=1,x,)))))


